# How to overwrite bootstrap table row background color

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a dynamically generated table and some rows should have a custom background color.

```
<table class="table table-striped">
 <tbody>
  <tr class="bg-coral">...</tr>
  <tr class="bg-coral">...</tr>
  <tr>...</tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I also want to use the `table-striped` class, just in case there are no colored rows, the alternate default colors will make it look good.

However, here as you see, though the first row has the custom class, it is not colored. I think the bootstrap `table-striped` odd row class is the reason.

Tried writing this, but no luck:

```
 .bg-coral{
    background-color: coral;
  }

.table-striped tbody tr.bg-coral, 
.table-striped tbody tr.bg-coral:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background-color: coral;
}
```

You can check the issue here:
https://jsfiddle.net/6kv3b47q/

What css class can I write, to make sure all `<tr>`s with the `bg-coral` class have the background color.

[image]

Comment: Can you please describe what exactly you want??

Comment: @Maulik, if a <tr> has the class bg-coral, then that row should get the background color.

Comment: I too need to over write table cell backgroung color, but cannot do it without removing table-striped class/feature

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for

```css
.table-striped tbody tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background-color: coral!important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table class="table table-striped">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>hello</td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>hiii</td>
   </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>hello</td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>hiii</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: doesnt that color every alternate row. I think you did not get my question.

Comment: @Qwerty so you want every row of your table have background-color "coral"?? or alternative???

Comment: The class bg-coral will be added to desired rows programmatically. So, all these rows should have the background color.

Comment: you can check the issue here - https://jsfiddle.net/6kv3b47q/